# Drop rows based on column values in Dask

Tags: python, null, rows, dask, drop

I am using `dask` to read a large csv file. I wanted to drop a few rows based on one column value. If for that particular column the row value is empty I want to remove the entire row.

I tried using `.dropna`:

```py
df = df.dropna(subset=['tier1_name'],how = 'any',axis =0)
```

However, I got this error:

```
TypeError: dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

So I used `.drop` instead:

```py
df.drop(df['tier1_name'].isnull(), axis = 0)
```

But then got this error:

```
"Drop currently only works for axis=1 or when columns is not None"
NotImplementedError: Drop currently only works for axis=1 or when columns is not None
```

I don't understand what should I use to execute the desired operation. Help!

Answer (score 1):

The key issue here is that, in general, `dask` will not know the number of rows or their content without evaluation, so row-based operations are not always easy to integrate.

As one solution to this, it's possible to use `.loc` with an appropriate mask, this pseudo-code might help:

```py
mask = df['tier1_name'].notna()
df_modified = df.loc[mask]
# note that if you need to use .isna(), then the mask value
# should be negated
```

Comment: I don't understand how using .loc will help in removing the rows.

Comment: I tried to mention the axis =0 in isna(). But it shows an error,  isna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: I tried updating the versions of dask and pandas but nothing really is working for me

Comment: Sultan's solution works, I just reproduced it. :) 

@krk, to answer your follow-up questions -- First, `axis=0` acts on rows which *is not* supported in Dask, for reasons that Sultan mentioned in their first sentence. Next, `.loc` isn't removing rows, it's creating a new dataframe with the rows you want to keep. Hope this helps.